# .sc domain "reserved in red". What does this mean?

Tags: domain-registration

I am interested in buying a two letter domain from the Seychelles (e.g. `ab.sc`). On reading the [qualifications document](http://www.nic.sc/en/forms/Rules-Governing-Qualifications-for-Registration.pdf) there is a line that states:

> All one and two letter domains name registrations are reserved in red under `.sc` (e.g. `ab.sc` , `12.sc`)

I don't understand what "reserved in red" means. Does anyone know?

Comment: Your best bet would be to contact the registry directly: http://www.nic.sc/en/contact-us.php

Answer (score 1):

two letter domains are used for special purpose .  and usually this will be premium domain. and some registers auctions two letter domains .  you can book it if you want but at extra cost. Most of the domain sellers not allow two letter domain to buy online it shows too short doamin name while entering domain for purchase.

Comment: Thanks for your input but this seems like speculation and doesn't really answer my question specifically about `.sc` domains.